# AWS Aurora performance degradation after upgrade from MySQL v5.6 to 8.0

Tags: mysql, query-performance, aws

Kindly suggest which parameters to look for..

Following is the Performance Insights for our MySQL 8.0 AWS Aurora cluster..

We are consuming 3000+ queries per second and most queries return immediately.. we just upgraded from MySQL 5.6 to 8.0 and on 5.6 we didn't have such an issue..

[image]

Following is additional information:

Show GLOBAL STATUS;
https://justpaste.it/20dx4

SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
https://justpaste.it/1sy4c

STATUS:

```
mysql> STATUS;
--------------
mysql  Ver 8.0.33 for macos12.6 on arm64 (Homebrew)

Connection id:      199671
Current database:   
SSL:            Cipher in use is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Current pager:      stdout
Using outfile:      ''
Using delimiter:    ;
Server version:     8.0.26 Source distribution
Protocol version:   10
Server characterset:    utf8mb4
Db     characterset:    utf8mb4
Client characterset:    utf8mb4
Conn.  characterset:    utf8mb4
TCP port:       3306
Binary data as:     Hexadecimal
Uptime:         1 day 2 hours 36 min 38 sec

Threads: 185  Questions: 329157339  Slow queries: 22588  Opens: 35941197  Flush tables: 3  Open tables: 10000  Queries per second avg: 3435.952
--------------


mysql> SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
Empty set (0.27 sec)
```

There are 25,000+ Databases on it.

8 Core, 64 GB RAM Machine hosted on AWS Aurora.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148302/discussion-on-question-by-hacker315-aws-aurora-performance-degradation-after-upg); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your ip 172-17-0-238 AWS Aurora Parameters Group
(these are all dynamic variables and will apply to new processes)

```
read_rnd_buffer_size=32768  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 873,098 
innodb_io_capacity=500  # from 200 to use more of available SSD IOPS 
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% of CPU cycles used for function
```

Answer (score 1):

hacker315
To avoid PERMISSIONS CHECKING delays of query to SUM from information_schema.tables,

```
USE test;   # your test database 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cloned_tables; 
CREATE TABLE cloned_tables LIKE information_schema.tables; 
ALTER TABLE test.cloned_tables ENGINE=INNODB;  # to AVOID memory table
INSERT INTO cloned_tables SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables; 
SELECT NOW(); 
SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM cloned_tables; 
SELECT NOW();
```

In a few days you may want to DROP TABLE test.cloned_tables;

Please post TEXT results of the SUM request.

Thank you